# 501 error on publish or save draft not showing up in wp debug.log

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I have a wordpress site that seems unable to save a draft or publish a page.

I went through the wp error log and debugged a few things in the theme. Those errors are fixed, but I am still unable to publish or save a draft of anything more than a few lines of text.

I get no errors in the wp debug log at /wp-content/debug.log

I changed to the unadulterated twenty seventeen theme. Still no luck saving.

And sometimes now I get a well-formed "Page not Found" at http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php instead of http://example.com//wp-admin/post.php?post=1058&action=edit

I can save a post if it has only a *few* words in it. If the text gets too long, it won't save. This is about a page and a half of text with links. It's a simple newsletter in the same format as we've done before.

I'd be grateful for suggestions as to what might be happening.

Comment: can we see what are the errors you have fixed? you need to show those errors. one more thing  does that post have any custom post type or error is coming for default one?

Comment: I've trashed the log. Sorry. It was an old artisteer theme that caused the errors. The point is, those errors are fixed. They don't show up anymore in the log. Yet the same 501 error happens even when I switch to the twenty-seventeen theme. The current log shows no errors, yet I still get a 501 error. In other words, the error I fixed has nothing to do with the 501 upon save draft or post. The 501 error does not post anything in the wp error log.

Comment: Okay, I've deactivated all plugins and changed the theme to twenty-seventeen. Error log shows no errors. No longer getting a 501, but I am getting a 404 upon attempts save draft or publish even just plain text over a few sentences. I can save under about five sentences, but if I go over that, I can't save. I suspect the problem may be server-based. I'd be grateful for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the FastCGI settings that had not been changed during a normal system upgrade. As suggested by the fact that I could save only a small amount of text in any new document, the problem was a system problem, not a wordpress problem. It resolved when FastCGI settings were mended.